# Create new columns to display repeating values based on combinations from other columns

Tags: r

I am attempting to write a R script that will create new columns based on values located in several different columns, and an ID field, and then fill these columns with repeating values based on the value field. This is what the starting data frame looks like:

```r
    df
   ID   row1   row2
1   1      x   <NA>
2   1   <NA>   <NA>
3   1   <NA>      y
4   2   <NA>      x
5   2      y   <NA>
6   3   <NA>      x
7   3   <NA>   <NA>
8   3   <NA>   <NA>
9   3      x   <NA>
10  4   <NA>      x
```

This is what I am hoping to create:

```r
df
   ID   row1   row2   x1   y1   x2   y2   x3 y3   x4 
1   1      x   <NA>    x <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA> 
2   1   <NA>   <NA>    x <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA> 
3   1   <NA>      y    x    y <NA> <NA> <NA> NA <NA> 
4   2   <NA>      x <NA> <NA>    x <NA> <NA> NA <NA> 
5   2      y   <NA> <NA> <NA>    x    y <NA> NA <NA> 
6   3   <NA>      x <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    x NA <NA> 
7   3   <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    x NA <NA> 
8   3   <NA>   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    x NA <NA> 
9   3      x   <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA>    x NA <NA> 
10  4   <NA>      x <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> <NA> NA    x 
>
```

I have been able to automate the creation of the empty columns based on each value-ID combination that exists. Value-pair combinations that do not have any values that would occupy them do not need to columns to be created, in this example that would be column hypothetical y4. I have attempting using nested if statements within for loops to automate the, but I am unable to get the values to repeat where necessary. Any ideas on how I can have the data frame copy values from above while the ID field is matched to the column?

Comment: I don't think this is a good idea creating endless amount of empty columns populated with very values- your data size will explode very fast. Why would you need something like that? Wouldn't it just better to have additional 2 columns that will keep track where `y` and `x` supposed to be?

Comment: The idea is to create a unique column based on each ID-value combination, because the data I am manipulating has multiple values associated within different IDs and I am attempting to match those functions to their specific paths based on their locations in the data frame. In reality only 15 extra columns were created using my method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is one approach that will produce your expected output with the difference that it only shows those value-ID combinations that are actually present in your data set (e.g. leaving the column y3, which is all `NA`)

```
df1 = data.frame(ID = df$ID, val = coalesce(df$row1,df$row2))

df1 %>% unite(comb, ID, val) %>% 
        mutate(val = df1$val, rn = row_number()) %>% 
        spread(comb,val) %>% mutate(ID = df$ID, row1 = df$row1, row2 = df$row2) %>% 
        group_by(ID) %>% fill(everything()) %>% 
        select(-rn) %>% select(-contains("NA"))

A grouped_df: 10 × 9
1_x 1_y 2_x 2_y 3_x 4_x ID  row1  row2
x   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   x     NA
x   NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  1   x     NA
x   y   NA  NA  NA  NA  1   x     y
NA  NA  x   NA  NA  NA  2   NA    x
NA  NA  x   y   NA  NA  2   y     x
NA  NA  NA  NA  x   NA  3   NA    x
NA  NA  NA  NA  x   NA  3   NA    x
NA  NA  NA  NA  x   NA  3   NA    x
NA  NA  NA  NA  x   NA  3   x     x
NA  NA  NA  NA  NA  x   4   NA    x
```